# How long before Christianity is on the SE Data Explorer?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I noticed the [data](http://data.stackexchange.com/) link in the footer, but following it I found that Christianity has not yet been added.  (With 3,410 questions we would be between Skeptics [3.8k] and Bicycles [3.2k].)

I am tagging this question with [bug](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) (since it is an unexpected behavior), even though I am guessing that this is just a less urgent feature that will be rolled out fairly soon.

Comment: I've got the DE open in a tab and keep hitting refresh. I think this is my personal most anticipated feature with our official graduation.

Comment: [Why hasn't Christianity made it into the Data Explorer yet?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185789)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an [extra hold up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185830/145951) due to a small glitch, but [we're live now](http://data.stackexchange.com/christianity%20stack%20exchange/queries)!

Answer (score 4):

There's a lag of around a week or so before the data explorer is updated.  Stay tuned!

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and the tag correction. (I was *really* uncertain about how to tag the question; "unexpected behavior" seemed slightly more accurate than "help with use", even though I assumed it was not a 'bug' in the usual sense.)

Comment: Geoff I don't want to open another post if this isn't an issue, but I just noticed that all the other sites on the DE got updated yesterday but C.SE didn't make the cut yet. Can you confirm when it might be available? Did it not get marked correctly for inclusion?

Comment: @Caleb the se mods just know patience is one of the virtues we are supposed to possess in abundance. :)